# extjs4 how to reset my modified store

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I would like to save my modified record in extjs4, and when I change some checkbox and go to the next page I haven't last modified record why? in extjs 3 I found this method pruneMOdifiedRecords (if true - save modification), but in extjs4 i haven't found this method
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save your changes you can ask your store to sync with the server using .sync() or to discard them then reload it using .reload()

Answer (score 0):

You can call [commitChanges](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-commitChanges) to save your modifications and [rejectChanges](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-rejectChanges) to reset them.

Comment: but i would like to save not in server, i like to save my modified changes (collect them) and then save in server

Answer (score 0):

To 'reject' all your changes in record you can use(ExtJS 3.x):

```
record.reject();
```

Here your all changes will be rejected which you made from creation of record or last commit of record.